# How to customize "MoneySent" intent UI screen for SendPayment intent using Sirikit in ios 10

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, xcode8, sirikit

I am using SendPayment intent for payment domain app. Basically, it shows two screens:-
1) Send Mooney
2) Money sent

Since the same intent view controller is shown for both the flows, can anybody share some tips how change the "Send Money" intent View by "Money Sent" view.

Also, in apple documentation, its written to use childViewController, but wondering on what basis it has to be used as in configure method, intenthandlingstatus is "undefined" always.

```
     func configure(with interaction: INInteraction!, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: ((CGSize) -> Void)!) {
// here interaction.intentHandlingStatus allways shows undefined
```

}

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: Is the SendPaymentIntent even working for you?

Comment: yes. Earlier it was not working. It was going to internet search. I have found a way to work.You need to pass paymentRecord in response, then it will work.

Comment: Would you mind providing me with some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any variables that are set by Apple to be able to tell the difference between the confirm step and the send step.

However if you structure your data correctly, there is a way to indirectly get this working.

Apple requires you to setup a PaymentRecord and attach it to each IntentResponse in confirmSendPayment:completion and handleSendPayment:completion:

What I am doing is I set the payment status to Pending in the confirm step and then to Completed in the handle step. So I can use the following code in the UI extension to show the proper UI for what step I am on:

```
INSendPaymentIntent *sendPaymentIntent = (INSendPaymentIntent *)interaction.intent;
INSendPaymentIntentResponse *sendPaymentResponse = (INSendPaymentIntentResponse *)interaction.intentResponse;
if (sendPaymentResponse.paymentRecord.status == INPaymentStatusPending) {
    // Confirm step
    [self setupUI:sendPaymentIntent forView:self.previewView];
    self.previewView.hidden = false;
    self.completeView.hidden = true;
} else if (sendPaymentResponse.paymentRecord.status == INPaymentStatusCompleted) {
    // Action performed step
    [self setupUI:sendPaymentIntent forView:self.completeView];
    self.previewView.hidden = true;
    self.completeView.hidden = false;
}
```